# Auto Size/Adjust Userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm new with VBA Programming, I have a `Userform` with `TextBoxes`,`Labels`, and `Checkboxes`.

My problem is how to Auto size or adjust the form, Because I have hidden `Textbox` and `Label`, Now if I click the `Button` it will unhide the `Texbox` and `Label` and also it will auto size the `Form` and the other controls.

I don't know how to start this.

Actual Result

[image]

Let's assume there is hidden `Label` and `Texbox` between `Team Name` and `Last Name` now I click the update `RadioButton` it will unhide the hidden `Label` and `Texbox` and adjust the form and other controls.

Expected Result

[image]

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say, the space required by the control *Tbx* hidden at the level 90pt from the top is 30pt. Therefore all controls below it should be moved down by 30pt when Tbx is made visible, and the form's height also increased by that same measure. The code below would accomplish that while at the same time unhiding the control.

```
Dim Ctl As MSForms.Controls

For Each Ctl In Me.Controls
    With Ctl
        If .Top >= 90 Then
            If .Visible = True Then
                .Top = Top + 30
            Else
                .Visible = True
            End If
        End If
    End With
Next Ctl
Me.Top = Top + 30
```

Two things would be different in practice.

1. You may have to hide the control again.
2. Your would create the control on the fly rather than keep it hidden.

If you plan on hiding the control again you would need an array of all affected control names and another array (or dimension) for their existing *Top*s. You would loop through all the names in the array and reset the top, like,

```
Me.Controls(Arr(0, i)).Top = Arr(1, i) + Iif(HideMe, 0, 30)
```

Look into creating the control on the fly. You should be able to simply create a copy of an existing control from which it inherits all properties. Any event code for that control needs to be prepared in advance, however.